# Angular post request to google got stuck by CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, google-signin

Url : http://local.m2.xxx.com/login

```
this.$http.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                'code': code,
                'redirect_uri': '***',
                'client_id': '******',
                'client_secret': '****',
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
            .success((data, status, headers, config)=> {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error((data, status) => {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
```

I also set Authorized JavaScript origins as http://local.m2.xxx.com

but still getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '***' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Cant find the solution

Comment: @Quentin from google develoepr console http://imgur.com/TmiBKyT

Comment: Are you familiar with CORS and how it works?

Comment: @DanielNalbach of course I know CORS, but I am saying that I already registered my domain to google aldready

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct endpoint?  For client side JS i believe the endpoint is: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth at least according to Google's [Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) page

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't post to that url. Instead you should just redirect your browser to it, or open it in a popup window.